# Cucumber selenium-webdriver Chrome

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running some tests in that I'm downloading a PDF from a webpage.  I'm running tests in Chrome and I want the file to go to a folder in my test pack.  I have the following block of code in my env file@

```
if ENV['chrome']
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome,
  :desired_capabilities => Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    'chromeOptions' => {
      'args' => [ "--window-size=1920,1080" ],
      'prefs' => {
      'download.default_directory' => File.expand_path("path/to/download"),
      'download.prompt_for_download' => false,
      'plugins.plugins_disabled' => ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
        }
      }
    )
  )
end
```

It clearly states that the prompt for download is false yet a window still appears asking me where I want to save the file once I've chosen to download the pdf.

Have I done something wrong in my block of code?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that question, I made a mistake my file path, doh!!!  I'll leave this question up in case anyone needs a solution like this for their tests.